# US citizen flying to France today and my passport expires in less than 2 months

Tags: schengen, passports, france, us-citizens

I'm an American citizen and I have a flight out to France today. One of my travel companions informed me that having a passport that expires in less than 2 months (on June 19th) might be a problem. Will I be able to travel or am I not going?

Comment: Every time I have been to France they have been really lax with checking passports. You can take the chance that they wont check it, or you can talk your way through.

Comment: @vikingsteve They might be lax at the border, but the check-in agent likely won't be.

Comment: @vikingsteve The reason they're so relaxed is because they have all the information beforehand from the airline. The idea that you can "talk your way through border control" is.. adorable though.

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with France, the problem is the airlines.   OP, **you will not be allowed to board**.  You need a new passport.

Comment: Sooooo... did you get on board? (Q asked 17 hours ago) - P.s. - get an emergency passport issued from your council/municipality (or whatever that is in America). Could possibly even try to have it issued with pick-up at the airport. Or maybe even sort it with customs at the airport itself. Though you really should've thought about this.

Comment: In addition to what others said: They are relaxed on the border since they do a simple check if the passport seems genuine and then scan the machine readable line and rfid chip after which the computer will match the information hey have and on their screen they see if it's ok or whether they have to do more inquiries. If it's ok from the system they have some basic questions, like purpose of trip, and if you donn't act suspicious you can move on

Comment: @rkeet US passport applications are processed by the federal government. Same-day processing requires going to one of [only 26 passport agencies](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/requirements/where-to-apply/passport-agencies.html).  There are thousands of [acceptance facilities](https://iafdb.travel.state.gov/DefaultForm.aspx) (for example, most post offices), but they just forward the application to the passport center and cannot provide same-day service.

Comment: @johannes there's no way to *get* to the border, however, if the passport doesn't meet the minimum requirement, because the airline will not allow the traveler on the plane.

Comment: Rule of thumb: **never** attempt to travel internationally with less than six months left on your passport.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that's a good rule of thumb.  The problem with rules of thumb, of course, is that they cause people to come and ask questions like "Do I need to renew my passport before flying to my country of citizenship 5.5 months before the passport expires?  Because I heard you can't travel with less than six months left on your passport?"  In other words, it can be important to know the difference between rules of thumb and actual rules.

Comment: @phoog Very true – that’s what makes it only a rule of thumb, rather than an actual rule. :-)

Comment: @phoog They be more like guidelines than actual rules.

Comment: I'm curious: this question is from yesterday, have you managed to take the flight?

Comment: what a shame this was a TDU !

Answer (score 47):

From [Visa policy of the Schengen area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Nationals_of_%27Annex_II%27_countries_and_territories_(visa_waiver_countries)):

> To be able to enter the Schengen Area/Bulgaria/Croatia/Cyprus/Romania visa waiver, the above Annex II nationals are required to:
>
> - have a travel document which is valid for at least 3 months after the intended date of departure and which has been issued in the previous 10 years

If your passport expires in less than two months, then unfortunately you will likely be refused boarding your plane by your airline.

Comment: Its 2 and a half months, but i take it that won't matter much here?

Comment: @Subterfugue The passport must be valid until three months after you intend to leave the Schengen area.  Whether it expires in less than two months or in two and a half months, it certainly does not meet that requirement.

Comment: this answer is incorrect.  it's not "likely".  you will, absolutely, of course, simply, be refused to board.

Comment: @Fattie It's likely, I've seen people discussing with the attendants just before boarding because their passport was actually expired the previous week and they were allowed to board anyway. It took them quite a long discussion (we were not happy being in the same queue), but in the end, they boarded.

Comment: what happened in the end, @Subterfugue !?

Comment: hi @ChatterOne - hmm.  You're pretty sure that case was: (1) departing from a US city, (2) going to France (next stop of the airplane is in France), (3) the person involved had a USA passport (and no other passports).

Answer (score 28):

To expand on [Greg's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/135095/20586), which already covers why you won't be allowed to enter the Schengen area, you might be interested in knowing that you can [get a US passport in a hurry](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/hurry.html) for an extra $60 (slightly more if you have them send the renewed passport by post).

Comment: ‘Tomorrow’ won’t be much good when the asker’s flight is _today_ (almost certainly already gone by now), but for future visitors, this is useful information.

Answer (score 10):

**TLDR: Was in exact same situation. Air France did not stop us from going or even comment on my passport expiring in 2.5 months.**

I was in the exact same situation, was flying to Paris (CDG) from Salt Lake City (SLC) and my passport expired in less than 2.5 months. At the boarding gate, they called my wife and I to check our passports / validity and luckily let us go through. We were initially thinking of cancelling anything but decided it was worth the risk as we wouldn't have gotten much back on the airfare. Hope it worked out for you too! Remember to renew your passport as soon as you're back!

Comment: Yes, much would depend on the nationality of the airline..  You'd expect a lot more haggling possible on Air France

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend asking the airline to change your departure date and drive to the nearest passport agency or center. Set up an appointment online while on the way there and get two passport photos taken. Bring your old passport. They can usually get you a passport in about 4-6 hours. Probably too late for OP, but hopefully it helps future travelers.

Comment: You're recommending going online to set up an appointment _while driving_???

Comment: @HenningMakholm it doesn't specify the person going for the passport drives..

Comment: @HenningMakholm setting up the appointment just takes a couple of minutes.  One could reasonably do this during a coffee break.  There are places in the US that are 1200 km from the nearest passport agency, in which case a few breaks will definitely be needed.  But it probably does make more sense to make the appointment before setting off on the trip.

Comment: @phoog Even further, since there isn't one in Alaska.

Comment: @AzorAhai Good point. And if you're on Maui you're not going to drive to Honolulu even if it's only 160 km.  Come to think of it, if you're in Alaska and don't have a passport, you're not exactly likely to be driving to Seattle any time soon, either.

Comment: @phoog You can enter Canada until your passport expires if you have a US passport (since this question was about a shortly expiring passport). But you'd probably just fly, it would be cheaper than driving

Comment: @phoog: How do Alaskans get their _first_ passport?

Comment: @HenningMakholm - you don't need to physically go to a passport center to get a passport, many post offices, local government offices, libraries, etc act as a _passport acceptance facility_ where you can submit an application for a passport or renewal.  But the best turnaround time you can expect without going to a passport agency (or paying an expediter service to go on your behalf) is 4 - 6 weeks for an expedited passport,